# Storyboard inside of a DataTrigger not triggering more than once on RaisePropertyChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, properties

I am using the MVVM model.

I have a dependency property, a boolean, called "`ResultOfUpdate`". It is changed whenever a user tries to run a command.

In the setter for this dependency property I am calling "`RaisePropertyChanged()`" method on the property name.

It is bound to a `DataTrigger` like so :

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResultOfUpdate}"  Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)" 
                                               AutoReverse="True">
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"  Value="0"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1"  Value="0.1"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.2"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.3"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.4"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.5"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6"  Value="0.6"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0.7"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0.8"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="0.9"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

...

```
 <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource statusStyle}"  
            Opacity="0" Text="Results updated!"      
            FontSize="10" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
```

I would like for each time this `bool` is set to true, the storyboard is played.

Confusingly, this storyboard is then triggered correctly the first time the user runs the command, updating the dependecy property to true.

Subsequent attempts have found that the dependency property setter code is entered, and the RaisePropertyChanged() method called - but the storyboard is not played again.

What have I done incorrectly here ?

Comment: Updated question as previous behaviour with regards to the constructor was as a result of me leaving a method in the constructor!

Comment: Has the value been set back to false so that there is a change to react to?  Otherwise, just continually setting the property to 'true' I don't think will get the desired effect you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also wish to get the property to react when it is set to false. I had thought about using enums to solve this, but it is not worth the effort (it seems quite difficult!). Is it possible to set it to null perhaps or something like this ?

Comment: I`ve got 2 questions. Why do you need RaisePropertyChanged() on dependency property? why do you have key times "0:0:0.1" and "0:0:0.3" twice with different values?

Comment: RaisePropertyChanged is to inform the view that the value has been updated. Storyboard was generated in Blend.

Comment: Dependency properties inform about their update automaticly. Maybe value of ResultOfUpdate remains true and does not change after first attempt?

Comment: They do not do this in the Galasoft implementation of MVVM. It is making it false after initially updating it, but it has no effect on the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly use an event trigger like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="I'm a text block" Name="theTextBlock"/>
    <Button Name="BeginButton">Begin</Button>
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="BeginButton">
            <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryboard">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="theTextBlock"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                        From="0.0" To="1.0" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>
</StackPanel>
```